# PHP join query returning unwanted result

Tags: php, mysql, join

My query is this and php is:

```
Select * 
from games 
left join players on games.id = players.id

echo "game:" .  $player . ",pass" . $pass...
```

I know its not correct php echo just faster writing

Output:

```
game:ost1232,pass:10,desc:Difficulty:Highest,players:Duiski,lad:0region:3;game:ost1232,pass:10,desc:Difficulty:Highest,players:testarn,lad:0,region:3;
```

but I want

```
game:ost1232,pass:10,desc:Difficulty:Highest,players:Duiski.testarn,lad:0,region:3;
```

The code outputs two games result but just want to input the players in the query with a dot in between.

- `Games` table: id, game, password, description, ladder, region.
- `Players`: id, player

I want to check players that join the game

Comment: Some db data would be great

Comment: Add a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Also you should use an intermediate table, I guess a user can play more games...

Comment: and selecting specific columns not just *

Comment: Fix the format of your question correctly. This is hard to read,

Comment: What is `testarn`? I suspect what you're looking for is `GROUP_CONCAT`, but it's hard to tell.

Comment: testarn its just a player

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that you should have an intermediate table if a user plays more games, so I would have these tables:

```
games
id
name

players
id
name

player_games
game_id
user_id
```

I would get the games of the user 'John' like this:

```
select 
players.name as player_name,
games.name as game_name
from games 
join player_games on player_games.game_id
join players on player_games.user_id = players.id
where players.name='John'
```

Optional: Add a Unique key constraint on player_games